# how to change css in jquery with set Attribute method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a simple of jquery ios button, and i want when user clicks on it and it is on, background color of page should be black and when button is off background color should be red for instance....

this is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/urbb4rgx/

what i appended to jquery:

```
var one = getElementsByClassName("switch"),
var two = getElementsByClassName("switchOn"),
if (two.hasOwnProperty("switchOn")) {

    document.getElementsByClassName("switchOn").background: red;

}
else {

        document.getElementsByClassName("switchOn").background: black;

}
```

please explain me what i did wrong

thanks...

Comment: Seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/urbb4rgx/1/

Comment: yes but background color should be changed after click on the button

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery try the following . --Update
Everything in your code looks fine . Just modify it to the following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.switch').click(function(){

       $(this).toggleClass("switchOn");

  $("body").toggleClass("black");

 });

      $('.switchBig').click(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass("switchBigOn");
     });
});
```

You will need to create a class to set Default background color :

```
body {
background-color:red; 
}

.black{
 background-color:black; 
}
```

Working example here: http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/bpgPvB